# Falha na instalação do Chart.js

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, eclipse

Estou tentando instalar o chart.js no meu projeto criado no eclipse mas toda vez que executo o codigo de instalação aparece erro.

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o que tem no seu arquivo de log?

Comment: Aonde eu vejo o arquivo de log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu já consegui. Primeiro eu desbilitei o firewall e depois usei o original.

```
npm config set registry http://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```